# How to clear GPU memory after using model?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to free up GPU memory after finishing using the model.

- I checked the `nvidia-smi` before creating and trainning the model: `402MiB /  7973MiB`
- After creating and training the model, I checked again the GPU memory status with  `nvidia-smi`: `7801MiB /  7973MiB`
- Now I tried to free up GPU memory with:

```
del model
torch.cuda.empty_cache() 
gc.collect()
```

and checked again the GPU memory:  `2361MiB /  7973MiB`

- As you can see not all the GPU memory was released (**I expected to get** 400~MiB / 7973MiB).
- I can only relase the GPU memory via terminal (`sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*`  and `kill` pid)

Is there a way to free up the GPU memory after I done using the model ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens becauce pytorch reserves the gpu memory for fast memory allocation. To learn more about it, see [pytorch memory management](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-memory-management). To solve this issue, you can use the following code:

```
from numba import cuda
cuda.select_device(your_gpu_id)
cuda.close()
```

However, this comes with a catch. It closes the GPU completely. So, you can't start training without restarting everything.

Comment: How can we restart? Simply running the code again?