# How to flush GPU memory using CUDA on WSL2

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda, numba, wsl-2

I have interrupted the training of the model in PyTorch on CUDA, which I've run on Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2). The dedicated GPU memory of NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080Ti was not flushed.

[image]

**What I have tried:**

- `gc.collect()` and `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` does not resolve the problem ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57860310))
- When running `numba.cuda.select_device(0)` to potentially `cuda.close()`, the notebook hangs ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70052988))
- After running `nvidia-smi` to potentially reset the GPU ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775894/15452880)), the command prompt hangs
- <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd>  to reset the graphics stack in Windows does not help ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717583))
- Restarting the notebook kernel as well as restarting the notebook server does not help
- Physical reset is not available

UPDATE:

Running `nvidia-smi` in the command prompt on Windows (not on WSL2) yields the following
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your actual environment.

suppose that you use anaconda window-venv

1. On cmd `>nvidia-smi` shows following.

[image: cmd->nvidia-smi]

2. Check pid of  python process name(`>envs\psychopy\python.exe`).
3. On cmd `taskkill /f /PID xxxx`

this could be help.

and you don't want doing like this.

if you feeling annoying you can run the script on prompt, it would be automatically flushing gpu memory.

Comment: I ran `nvidia-smi` in the Windows cmd. A screenshot is in the updated question. I don't find `\psychopy\python.exe`, though nor do I see any similar processes, which it would make sense to kill. Do you see any?

Comment: I use windows only, i'm always see .\python.exe but your env not showing. how about command run on wsl environment

Comment: I think you are not using gpu in pytorch similar problem is in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197286/how-can-i-flush-gpu-memory-using-cuda-physical-reset-is-unavailable which hold your gpu memory check first

Comment: As I mentioned in the description, when running `nvidia-smi` on WSL2, the command prompt freezes, so I don't get any info about it. Nevertheless, I have managed to physically reboot the machine. Problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: you getting hard time. so sorry. try 'nvidia-smi -r' or 'nvidia-smi --gpu-reset' may be this is majino line.